# Change background colour with javascript with 2 colours

Tags: javascript, html, background-color

I'm trying to have a button on my webiste that if you press it the background color will change to blue which i have, but i'm trying to code that if you press it again it'll change to white again.

```js
function myFunction() {   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "lightblue";
}

function my1Function() {   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "lightgrey";
}

function my2Function() {   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "pink";
}

function my3Function() {   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "lightgreen";
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1></h1>
</header>

<br>

<form action="#">
<label for="fname">Uw naam:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Lightblue</button>
<button type="button" onclick="my1Function()">Lightgrey</button>
<button type="button" onclick="my2Function()">Pink</button>
<button type="button" onclick="my3Function()">Lightgreen</button>
```

I tried using alternatives such as case1, case2, case3 etc.

Comment: Are you saving the state of color on refresh as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not saving the state of color on refresh or rerendering then this could be one of the solutions.

```js
var blue = 0;
function myFunction() {   
    if(blue == 0){
  
  
    document.body.style.backgroundColor= "lightblue";
        blue = 1;
  }
  else{
    document.body.style.backgroundColor= "white";
        blue = 0;
  }
}

function my1Function() {   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "lightgrey";
}

function my2Function() {   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "pink";
}

function my3Function() {   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "lightgreen";
}
```

```html
<header>
<h1></h1>
</header>

<br>

<form action="#">
<label for="fname">Uw naam:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Lightblue</button>
<button type="button" onclick="my1Function()">Lightgrey</button>
<button type="button" onclick="my2Function()">Pink</button>
<button type="button" onclick="my3Function()">Lightgreen</button>
```

Comment: a `ternary conditional operator` would be appropriate and perform faster then an if/else statement!

Answer (score 1):

By clicking on the `button` you could add a `class` to the `body` which represents your colour. On clicking the `button` again you can simply check the [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) of `body`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.onclick = function(){
    if(document.body.classList.contains(this.textContent)){
      document.body.className = ''
    }
    else{
      document.body.className = '';
      document.body.classList.add(this.textContent)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.Lightblue{background-color: lightblue}
.Lightgrey{background-color: lightgrey}
.Pink{background-color: pink}
.Lightgreen{background-color: lightgreen}
```

```html
<button type="button">Lightblue</button>
<button type="button">Lightgrey</button>
<button type="button">Pink</button>
<button type="button">Lightgreen</button>
```

*This quick sample assumes you are not using classes on the `body` for anything else and that the names of your colours are single worded. If that is not the case, use `data-attribute` instead.*

### Edit

As Javascript requested, the mentioned version which does not collide with other potential usecases.

It sets a [`data-attribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead of a class and uses styles which regard those `data-attributes`.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.onclick = function(){
    const tColour = this.dataset.color;
  
    if(document.body.dataset.color === tColour){
      document.body.dataset.color = ''
    }
    else{
      document.body.dataset.color = tColour
    }
  }
})
```

```css
[data-color=Lightblue]{background-color: lightblue}
[data-color=Lightgrey]{background-color: lightgrey}
[data-color=Pink]{background-color: pink}
[data-color=Lightgreen]{background-color: lightgreen}
```

```html
<button type="button" data-color="Lightblue">Lightblue</button>
<button type="button" data-color="Lightgrey">Lightgrey</button>
<button type="button" data-color="Pink">Pink</button>
<button type="button" data-color="Lightgreen">Lightgreen</button>
```

Comment: this removes all classes from the body including classes that must not be related to this at all.

Comment: Yes it does, as already stated in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
const body = document.querySelector('body')

function myFunction() {   
  body.style.backgroundColor= "lightblue";
  if (body.style.backgroundColor !== '#fff') {
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'
  }
}

function my1Function() {   
  body.style.backgroundColor= "lightgrey";
  if (body.style.backgroundColor !== '#fff') {
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'
  }
}

function my2Function() {   
  body.style.backgroundColor= "pink";
  if (body.style.backgroundColor !== '#fff') {
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'
  }
}

function my3Function() {   
  body.style.backgroundColor= "lightgreen";
  if (body.style.backgroundColor !== '#fff') {
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#fff'
  }
}
```

Comment: How does this change anything?

Comment: Oops - fixed it.

Comment: `body.style.backgroundColor !== '#fff'` is always going to be true since you set it right before.

Comment: If you use so much repetitive code then you need to over think your logic

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check in what "state" the color is in and then change it accordingly.
you can optimize the code and use more variables but the overall idea is that you should use and if statement to check the "state".

for example

```
function myFunction() {
const background = document.body.style.backgroundColor;
if(background  === "lightblue"){ 
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
} else {
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply just do something like this

```
<button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = lightblue';">pink</button>

<button onclick="document.body.style.backgroundColor = pink';">pink</button>
```

This will work

Comment: How does that solve the asked question?

Answer (score -1):

You can improve the code to be shorter and more efficient by not using `onclick` attributes as triggers.

Use an `eventListener`to listen to click events within all your buttons.

Then add a `data`-attribute that contains the color-name. Then you use `e.target.dataset` to get the value and include that as color:

```js
let selected_color;

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(el =>
  el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    let clicked_color = e.target.dataset.btnColor;
    selected_color = (selected_color === clicked_color) ? '' : clicked_color;
    document.body.style.background = selected_color;
  })
)
```

```html
<header>
<h1></h1>
</header>

<br>

<form action="#">
<label for="fname">Uw naam:</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button type="button" data-btn-color="lightblue">Lightblue</button>
<button type="button" data-btn-color="lightgrey">Lightgrey</button>
<button type="button" data-btn-color="pink">Pink</button>
<button type="button" data-btn-color="lightgreen">Lightgreen</button>
```

Comment: Setting classes is better practice than setting inline styles.

Comment: `background` also includes other properties which might be set elsewhere.

Comment: if you want to set a specific color to the bodies background then inline is actually better. The specificity weight ensures that it applies and its cleaner then to create dozens of classes just to cover every possible color. This way you only have to set it in HTML.

Comment: I respect your opinion, I just disagree. Still you should set `style.backgroundColor` and not `style.background`.